# Swift: NSCollectionViewItem properties not change

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I am building a `Cocoa`  `Swift` app which have `NSCollectionViews` and have an `NSCollectionView` which has custom `NSCollectionViewItem` which has like below as in photo.

[image]

My purpose is building something like a calendar and as you understand from the image, I want to change date value and date string. Even tried it like below couldn't achieve it and did not understand what effects it.

Here is my custom NSCollectionViewItem

```
class CalendarDateCell: NSCollectionViewItem {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var dateNameString: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateNumberString: NSTextField!
    
    
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }
    
}
```

Here is my `itemForRepresentedObjectAt` function.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        // 4
        let item = calendarCollectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "CalendarDateCell"), for: indexPath)
        guard let collectionViewItem = item as? CalendarDateCell else {return item}
        
        
        
        switch indexPath.item % 3 {
        case 0,1:
            collectionViewItem.dateNameString.stringValue = "0-1"
        case 2:
            collectionViewItem.dateNameString.stringValue = "3"
        default:
            break
        }
        
        return collectionViewItem
    }
```

I tried it for testing, UI is done work but I did not change the property of the `NSCollectionViewItem` as a change of `NSIndexPath`

Then I added a `String` variable to `NSCollectionViewItem` and observe it with `didSet` method and I can change the variable but it's not effective for UI elements of `AppKit`.

How can I fix the problem? Any suggestions?

Edit:

I add a model for `NSCollectionViewItem`

```
var calendarModel: CalendarModel = CalendarModel() {
        didSet {
            dateNameString.stringValue = calendarModel.name
        }
    }
```

Then change it in controller as

```
collectionViewItem.calendarModel.name = "1231"
```

but never affects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On-Topic: you should represent the data of the cells as a separate list of models. And then the function you have written there should only read the model from the list of models. Off-Topic: Curious: is this a fairly "new" macOS app? If it is, why not use `SwiftUI` instead of AppKit? :)

Comment: OnTopic: thank you so much Sajjon, can you provide a simple example for the question? OffTopic: yeah it's new macOS app because the company not ready for built it with SwiftUI yet so they wanted to build it with `Cocoa` never mentioned `SwiftUI` but I wish I start to build it with `SwiftUI`

Comment: There is literally thousands of tutorials on this. I would implement a method in `CalendarDateCell` which takes the model and populates the data with its properties. Achives nice encapsulation.

Comment: Thank you but I want to be sure if you mean what I understand as I edited for encapsulation. Can you verify it if it's true or not?

Comment: Are you calling `reloadData()` after model changes? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview/1528264-reloaddata

Comment: yeah, but never changed. I looked at `https://dev.to/onmyway133/making-nscollectionview-programatically-in-swift-2i85` and `https://www.raywenderlich.com/783-nscollectionview-tutorial` but all of them are same as mine.